# ASP.NET Core Azure AD Auth - Redirect URI incorrect for network web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am creating a web app in ASP.NET Core that uses Azure AD for authentication. When debugging, everything works fine. When published to the local web server, an error occurs:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application

Right now, I have the reply_url in azure as https://localhost:5000/signin-oidc, and the callback url in appsettings.json as "/signin-oidc".
When registering the app in Azure, you cannot set a local network location as a reply_url (eg. \\server\folderlocation). How can I set this up to have the redirect urls match?

Also, would IIS interfere with this somehow since I set it up like regular ASP.NET apps? I haven't messed with the IIS settings at all, and I've read with ASP.NET Core you basically have to make it pass through IIS because of the properties of aspnetcore.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot declare two redirect url's then you need to change your reply_url. Or alternatively you can create another client for debugging purposes within your OAuth2 provider so that you want need to deal with this issue.

For the latter approach, Please note that you need to divide your app.settings one for debugging another for production.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I don't know what to change my redirect url to. The path in the appsettings.json needs to start with '/' otherwise it throws an error. The url in azure must start with https or `http://localhost`.

Comment: when you publish what is the address of your application? write full address of your home page

Comment: And that should be both in azure and appsettings.json? Azure won't let me use that as a url. (doesn't start with https or `http://localhost`)

Comment: Is your web server accessable from internet? The servername is unknown for Azure, you need to configure the server address with valid host or public ip which could be access over internet.

Comment: @TaoZhou - Right now no, the server is not accessible from the internet. Will that be a problem? How would I start configuring the server so it's still not accessible from the internet but can authenticate with azure? I find it hard to believe it's not possible!

Comment: @aweyeahdawg login your server, try to access `http://servername/appname`, will it be accessable? If it does, try to login your web app to check redirect. If your web server is not internet accessable, you will not able to authenticate with azure if the end user's computer could not connect the server.